# How can I cut the mac address out of DHCPDUMP?

Tags: networking, dhcp, grep, cut-command

I am trying to use `dhcpdump` to recognize people logging onto my home network and give them a tailor made greeting using a credential file.

I cannot get the mac address out of the results of `dhcpdump`. The machine I am running the script is not the DHCP server.

dhcpdump results :

```
  TIME: 2015-09-02 22:42:48.909
    IP: 0.0.0.0 (xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx) > 255.255.255.255 (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
    OP: 1 (BOOTPREQUEST)
 HTYPE: 1 (Ethernet)
  HLEN: 6
```

The command I'm trying is:

```
dhcpdump -i eth0 | grep IP: | cut -d"(" -f2 | cut -d")" -f1
```

but it just won't work. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep` (thanks to A.B. for the `--line-buffered` suggestion):

```
dhcpdump -i eth0 | grep --line-buffered -Po ' *IP: .*?\(\K[^)]*'
dhcpdump -i eth0 | grep --line-buffered -Po ' *IP: .*\(\K[^)]*'
```

The first one will extract the first address, the second one will extract the last address;

`grep` command #1 breakdown:

- `*`: matches any number of  characters
- `IP:`: matches an `IP:` string
- `.*?`: matches any number of any character lazily
- `\(`: matches a `(` character
- `\K`: discards the previous match
- `[^)]*`: matches any number of any character not `)` lazily

`grep` command #2 breakdown:

- `*`: matches any number of  characters
- `IP:`: matches an `IP:` string
- `.*`: matches any number of any character greedily
- `\(`: matches a `(` character
- `\K`: discards the previous match
- `[^)]*`: matches any number of any character not `)` lazily

Sample output:

```
user@debian ~ % echo "IP: 0.0.0.0 (xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx) > 255.255.255.255 (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)" | grep -Po ' *IP: .*?\(\K[^)]*' 
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
user@debian ~ % echo "IP: 0.0.0.0 (xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx) > 255.255.255.255 (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)" | grep -Po ' *IP: .*\(\K[^)]*'
ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: The RegEx is ok, but I have no output with the command `dhcpdump`. :\

Comment: You need `--line-buffered` for `grep`

Comment: @A.B. Strangely for me it works also without the `--line-buffered` switch, however I tested it using `tail -f foo | grep '.'` and running `echo bar >> foo` in another terminal, so I guess that makes a difference somehow. Thanks

Comment: Hmm, ok, it's interesting... o_O

Comment: And another thing: With `sudo dhcpdump -i eth0` I have `    IP: 192.168.20.67 (d8:d3:85:79:ad:aa) > 255.255.255.255 (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)` with some leading spaces. Therefore in my case, the `^IP: ` fails.

Comment: @A.B. Thanks again. I wasn't sure if there were actually some or if OP just added them himself. Fixed

Comment: I have added the correct output format into the question. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need `grep` you have to use the switch `--line-buffered`

An easier way is `mawk` and the `-W interactive`

```
sudo dhcpdump -i eth0 | mawk -W interactive '/IP: / {gsub(/\(|\)/,"", $3); print $3}'
```

*Sample output* (you have to wait some seconds)

```
64:31:50:30:ca:1e
40:61:86:7:ce:34
0:24:21:b1:6f:32
54:27:1e:19:7c:3b
0:23:7d:5f:4a:e8
```

If you need `grep` you have to use the switch `--line-buffered`

Comment: I don't know if I am using a different version of awk but it doesn't even recognize the '-W' flag ......GNU AWK 4.0.1

Comment: Sorry, `mawk` is correct.